# Adding data from txt file to mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a dataset that has this format (userid, movieid, rating, timestamp), eks:

"196    242 3   881250949

186    302 3   891717742

22     377 1   878887116

244    51  2   880606923

166    346 1   886397596"

The timestamp is not relevant for me.

I have a Rating model that looks like this:

var Ratings = new Schema({
    user: String,
    movieid: Number,
    rating: Number
});.

Now my question is, how do I add the data from the txt file into my mongodb database?

Thx!

Newbeginner in nodejs.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some real code, we're not gonna code for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if `userid` and `movieid` links to another mongo documents you should change your schema and adding an `ObjectId` types instead.
Secondly, to answer your question, you should take a look at the `fs` built in module. [fs documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)